# horizantal form to vertical on a mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form in the bottom of this page:

When you look at the form from an Iphone 4, 5, 6 etc screen size, the button is totally messed up.
I would like to make it responsive, so when you see the page on a mobile, the form will get vertical instead of horizontal.

But to be honest I really do not know how I can do that? Does anybody have a suggestion?

Best Regards

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nqpey0yL/ is a very simple version of what you want, derived from the bootstrap docs (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms). Please share the code of what you have done so far if you want a more specific answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one change

```
@media screen (max-width: 480px){
  .signup-wide #signupForm{
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

here is a minimal complete example.
In this **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d9qxex2j/)** , form will become vertical below screen width of `480px`

```css
#signupForm{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
 #signupForm{
  flex-direction : column;
 }
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="signupForm">
 <input type="text">
 <input type="text">
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I don't see that that OP is using flexbox.

Comment: `.signup-wide form {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
}`

it's from his code

Answer (score 1):

Using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries):

```
@media (max-width: 750px) {

    .signup-wide form {
        display: block; /* Instead of flex */
    }

    .signup-wide form .form-group {
        width: 100%; /* Instead of 33% */
    }

    .signup-wide form .btn {
        width: 100%; /* Instead of 33% */
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. This defently did almost what I wanted. One thing I do not understand. The .signup-wide form .form-group is set to 100%, but it is only filling out around 85 %. How can that be?
(Just updated my question with the screenshot)

Answer (score 1):

Simply apply row logic:

```
<form class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" />
  </div>
  <button class="btn col-sm-4">Ja - tak</button>
</form>
```

---

*Notes*
Make sure `input` is `width: 100%`. You can adjust break-point by changing `-sm` to other break-point: `-xs`/`-md`/`-lg`

Comment: in horizontal forms `.form-group` can replace `.row`

Answer (score 0):

You should look into media queries for your stylesheet.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

> What is a Media Query?
>
> Media query is a CSS technique introduced in CSS3.
> It uses the @media rule to include a block of CSS properties only if a certain condition is true.
>
> Example
>
> If the browser window is smaller than 500px, the background color will change to lightblue:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
    background-color: lightblue;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert this  and after that play with it :)

```css
@media all and (max-width:800px) //800px for tablets and phones.
{
.signup-wide form
  {
        display: block; 
        float: none; 
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I just tried your code, but when I run the code the form is only around 30%, even if the code says 100%. Could you have a clue why that happens?

Answer (score 0):

```css
#signupForm{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    #signupForm{
        flex-direction : column;
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="signupForm">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```